# Let a , b and c be integers such that a | b and b | c . Prove that ab | c^ 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

I am not sure how to prove this but this is what I have so far.

$b= ak$ for some integer $k$ and
$c= bl$ for some integer $l$

Then........

Here is where I am stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$b=ak \tag1$$

and

$$c=bl$$
from $(1)$

$$c=(ak)l \implies c^2=a^2k^2l^2$$

Since $b=ak$, we can write :

$$ c^2=a^2k^2l^2=a \cdot(ak)\cdot kl^2=ab \cdot kl^2$$

Since $$c^2= ab \times m ~~\text{where}~~ m=kl^2 \implies ab \mid c^2$$

Answer (score 2):

... then $c = akl$, so $c^2 = bl\cdot akl = ab\cdot kl^2$

Comment: Can you please explain how c = alk and c^2 = bl*akl?

Comment: @PhillipMc You have already said that $c = bl$ and that $b = ak$. Insert one into the other, and you get $c = bl = (b)l = (ak)l = akl$. Finally, we have $c = bl$ and $c = akl$, so if we multiply these two together, we get $c^2 = c\cdot c = bl\cdot akl = abkl^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  prove first $m \mid n, \,p \mid q \implies m\cdot p \mid n \cdot q\,$, then combine the following:

- $a \mid b \implies ab \mid b^2$
- $b \mid c \implies b^2 \mid c^2$